# How can i get the Parameters from Behat.yml to a php file?

Tags: php, behat, mink

I have a Behat.yml

```
  default :
     context :
       parameters :
            user: xyz
            password : abc
```

Also i have a file called FeatureContext.php which retrieves the values from behat.yml through

```
   public function iExample($user, $password)
    {
       $userName=$this->getParameter($user);
    }
```

But it throws an error like

```
   "Call to undefined method FeatureContext::getParameter()"
```

Am i missing something ? .. i have also added autoload.php in FeatureContext.php through

```
   require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Please let know , if you have any idea why it is happening ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `FeatureContext` class has to extend `BehatContext` and then you get the parameters-array as an argument in the constructor of `FeatureContext`. See http://michaelheap.com/behat-selenium2-webdriver/ for an example.

Edit:

```
class FeatureContext extends BehatContext
{
    private $params = array();

    public function __construct(array $parameters)
    {
        $this->params = $parameters;
    }

    public function iExample($user, $password)
    {
        $userName = $this->params['user'];
    }
}
```

I haven't used Behat for a while, but you probably get the idea.

Comment: I have tried with BehatContext also . It gives me the same error ....                     "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method FeatureContext::getParameter() in D:\
mypgms\Again\features\bootstrap\FeatureContext.php on line 61"

Comment: See my edited answer. Don't use getParameter (it doesn't seem to exist and I can't find it from the API docs either), instead save the parameters to a member variable in constructor for later use.